cannot create R4 context using hapi fhir
I'm trying to create a fhir client using hapi fhir 7.2.1, but FhirContext.forR4() throws an exception (I've tried prior versions with similar results). I've also tried forR4B() and forR5(). They all result in errors.
FYI: I'm new to Android and Kotlin.
I started by creating an "empty activity" project in Android Studio. Then added this code at the beginning of OnCreate():
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
try {
    val ctx: FhirContext = FhirContext.forR4()
    val client = ctx.newRestfulGenericClient("https://hapi.fhir.org/baseR4")
    val patient = client.read().resource(Patient::class.java).withId("example").execute()
    val string = ctx.newJsonParser().setPrettyPrint(true).encodeResourceToString(patient)
    println(string)
} catch (e : Throwable) {
    println("Error: " + e.message)
} finally {
    println("Done")
}

The exception thrown says:
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field INSTANCE of type Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier; in class Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier; or its superclasses (declaration of 'org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AllowAllHostnameVerifier' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar!classes5.dex)

Is there something wrongly configured in my setup? Or might this be due to dependency conflicts I had to resolve when building? I'm not sure I'm using the right approach.
In order to get rid of warnings on project sync when i included dependencies for hapi fhir (Failed to resolve: com.google.guava:listenablefuture:1.0 and Failed to resolve: com.google.guava:guava:32.1.1-jre), I had to add to build.gradle.kts
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.capabilitiesResolution.withCapability("com.google.guava:listenablefuture") {
        select("com.google.guava:guava:0")
    }
}

And to fix this build error
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeJavaResWorkAction
   > 2 files found with path 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES' from inputs:
      - C:\Users\guim\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpclient\4.5.13\e5f6cae5ca7ecaac1ec2827a9e2d65ae2869cada\httpclient-4.5.13.jar
      - C:\Users\guim\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpcore\4.4.13\853b96d3afbb7bf8cc303fe27ee96836a10c1834\httpcore-4.4.13.jar
     Adding a packaging block may help, please refer to
     https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/8.5/com/android/build/api/dsl/Packaging
     for more information

I had to add this to build.gradle.kts
android {
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += setOf(
                "META-INF/DEPENDENCIES",
            )}
    }
}

Any clue why FhirContext.forR4() fails?
Thanks for any help.
